# R: ggplot2 - Manually set point shape, line type, and colour according to label

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to make a plot with manually set colours and manually set shapes for both points and lines. The dataframe I'm working with has the following format:

```
"n" "times"     "algorithms"    "shapes"    "linetypes"     "colours"
1   0.000271833 "algo1"         "x"         "solid"         "blue"
11  0.000612195 "algo1"         "x"         "solid"         "blue"
1   0.000267802 "algo2"         "x"         "solid"         "red"
11  0.000644297 "algo2"         "x"         "solid"         "red"
1   0.000280468 "algo3"         "x"         "solid"         "green"
11  0.000816817 "algo3"         "x"         "solid"         "green"
1   0.000452015 "algo4"         "x"         "solid"         "black"
11  0.00271677  "algo4"         "x"         "solid"         "black"
1   0.000271255 "algo5"         "o"         "dashed"        "blue"
11  0.000622194 "algo5"         "o"         "dashed"        "blue"
1   0.000271107 "algo6"         "o"         "dashed"        "red"
11  0.000701686 "algo6"         "o"         "dashed"        "red"
1   0.000267631 "algo7"         "o"         "dashed"        "green"
11  0.000723341 "algo7"         "o"         "dashed"        "green"
1   0.000451016 "algo8"         "o"         "dashed"        "black"
11  0.00124079  "algo8"         "o"         "dashed"        "black"
```

This dataframe contains execution times for 8 different algorithms. I would like to achieve the following: I would like to plot the points with crosses for algorithms `alg1` to `alg4` and with points (filled, if possible) for algorithms `alg5` to `alg8`. In a similar fashion, I want lines connecting points so that the lines drawn show the growth of the execution time of each algorithm, and I want some of the lines to be solid, and others to be dashed. I also want to use particular colours for each algorithm, as indicated in the column "colours".

Now, I've managed to make quite some progress:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=n, y=times, group=algorithms, linetype=linetypes, pch=shapes, colour=colours)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    theme(legend.position="bottom") +
    xlab("n") +
    ylab(paste0("Execution time (ms)")) +
    ggtitle("asdf")
```

But this gives me a most disagreeable legend:
[image]

I would like to have a legend with the names of the algorithms next to the picture of their corresponding line and point types, and obviously colour.

I've looked around this site, and others, but to no avail. It really has been difficult since most people do not go beyond the manual setting of colours, shapes of points, and line types. I only need to know how to make this extra step. I'm sure it is quite easy to do it, but I'm completely at a loss.

Thanks to you all.

Comment: Indeed, @dipetkov nailed it. However, the point types needed some more tuning. The "x", and "o" did not work any more with their solution so I changed them for a 4 and a 1 ("x"->4, "o"->1, see http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-point-shapes) and now everything is fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the color/linetype/shape scales manually.

```r
library("tidyverse")

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~n, ~times, ~algorithms, ~shapes, ~linetypes, ~colours,
  1L, 0.000271833, "algo1", "x", "solid", "blue",
  11L, 0.000612195, "algo1", "x", "solid", "blue",
  1L, 0.000267802, "algo2", "x", "solid", "red",
  11L, 0.000644297, "algo2", "x", "solid", "red",
  1L, 0.000280468, "algo3", "x", "solid", "green",
  11L, 0.000816817, "algo3", "x", "solid", "green",
  1L, 0.000452015, "algo4", "x", "solid", "black",
  11L, 0.00271677, "algo4", "x", "solid", "black",
  1L, 0.000271255, "algo5", "o", "dashed", "blue",
  11L, 0.000622194, "algo5", "o", "dashed", "blue",
  1L, 0.000271107, "algo6", "o", "dashed", "red",
  11L, 0.000701686, "algo6", "o", "dashed", "red",
  1L, 0.000267631, "algo7", "o", "dashed", "green",
  11L, 0.000723341, "algo7", "o", "dashed", "green",
  1L, 0.000451016, "algo8", "o", "dashed", "black",
  11L, 0.00124079, "algo8", "o", "dashed", "black"
)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = n, y = times,
    linetype = algorithms,
    shape = algorithms,
    colour = algorithms
  )) +
  geom_line() +
  # Comment out `geom_point` to check that the line type is 
  # as specified but is overplotted by the shape in the legend
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  xlab("n") +
  ylab(paste0("Execution time (ms)")) +
  ggtitle("asdf") +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = deframe(df %>% select(algorithms, colours))
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values = deframe(df %>% select(algorithms, linetypes))
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(
    values = deframe(df %>% select(algorithms, shapes))
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>